# pandas_ta parabolic SAR giving wrong values for yfinance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cryptocurrency, yfinance

I made a function that uses the psar function from the pandas_ta library. This function seems to work incorrectly, it gives the PSARl, PSARs and PSARr values on the wrong dates. While using an interval of 1 day on BTC-USD I get the following output:

Used function:

```
psar = df.ta.psar(high=df['High'], low=df['Low'], close=df['Close'], af0=0.02, af=0.02, max_af=0.2)
print(psar)
```

Output:

```
            PSARl_0.02_0.2  PSARs_0.02_0.2  PSARaf_0.02_0.2  PSARr_0.02_0.2
Date                                                                       
2021-10-29             NaN             NaN             0.02               0
2021-10-30             NaN    62927.609375             0.02               1
2021-10-31             NaN    62927.609375             0.04               0
2021-11-01             NaN    62813.478125             0.06               0
2021-11-02    59695.183594             NaN             0.02               1
2021-11-03    59695.183594             NaN             0.02               0
2021-11-04    59786.135781             NaN             0.02               0
2021-11-05    59875.268925             NaN             0.02               0
2021-11-06    59962.619406             NaN             0.02               0
2021-11-07    60048.222877             NaN             0.02               0
2021-11-08    60132.114279             NaN             0.04               0
2021-11-09    60433.779395             NaN             0.06               0
2021-11-10    60919.572788             NaN             0.08               0
2021-11-11    61549.176965             NaN             0.08               0
2021-11-12    62128.412808             NaN             0.08               0
2021-11-13    62333.914062             NaN             0.08               0
2021-11-14    62333.914062             NaN             0.08               0
2021-11-15    62850.370938             NaN             0.08               0
2021-11-16             NaN    68789.625000             0.02               1
2021-11-17             NaN    68594.159219             0.04               0
2021-11-18             NaN    68191.009256             0.06               0
2021-11-19             NaN    67492.596279             0.08               0
2021-11-20             NaN    66549.602952             0.08               0
2021-11-21             NaN    65682.049091             0.08               0
2021-11-22             NaN    64883.899538             0.10               0
2021-11-23             NaN    63963.493569             0.12               0
2021-11-24             NaN    62963.805747             0.12               0
2021-11-25             NaN    62084.080463             0.12               0
2021-11-26             NaN    61309.922214             0.14               0
2021-11-27             NaN    60226.300292             0.14               0
2021-11-28             NaN    59294.385438             0.14               0
2021-11-29             NaN    58492.938664             0.14               0
```

While looking at the yfinance chart for the BTC-USD I should not get a 1 in the PSARr column at 2021-10-30 but I somehow am. It's really random because some values are correct but some of them aren't. What am I doing wrong or is there something wrong within the function?

Thanks!

picture:
[image: Yfinance screenshot]

Other data:

```
                    Open          High           Low         Close  \
Date                                                                 
2021-10-29  60624.871094  62927.609375  60329.964844  62227.964844   
2021-10-30  62239.363281  62330.144531  60918.386719  61888.832031   
2021-10-31  61850.488281  62406.171875  60074.328125  61318.957031   
2021-11-01  61320.449219  62419.003906  59695.183594  61004.406250   
2021-11-02  60963.253906  64242.792969  60673.054688  63226.402344   
2021-11-03  63254.335938  63516.937500  61184.238281  62970.046875   
2021-11-04  62941.804688  63123.289062  60799.664062  61452.230469   
2021-11-05  61460.078125  62541.468750  60844.609375  61125.675781   
2021-11-06  61068.875000  61590.683594  60163.781250  61527.480469   
2021-11-07  61554.921875  63326.988281  61432.488281  63326.988281   
2021-11-08  63344.066406  67673.742188  63344.066406  67566.828125   
2021-11-09  67549.734375  68530.335938  66382.062500  66971.828125   
2021-11-10  66953.335938  68789.625000  63208.113281  64995.230469   
2021-11-11  64978.890625  65579.015625  64180.488281  64949.960938   
2021-11-12  64863.980469  65460.816406  62333.914062  64155.941406   
2021-11-13  64158.121094  64915.675781  63303.734375  64469.527344   
2021-11-14  64455.371094  65495.179688  63647.808594  65466.839844   
2021-11-15  65521.289062  66281.570312  63548.144531  63557.871094   
2021-11-16  63721.195312  63721.195312  59016.335938  60161.246094   
2021-11-17  60139.621094  60823.609375  58515.410156  60368.011719   
2021-11-18  60360.136719  60948.500000  56550.792969  56942.136719   
2021-11-19  56896.128906  58351.113281  55705.179688  58119.578125   
2021-11-20  58115.082031  59859.878906  57469.726562  59697.195312   
2021-11-21  59730.507812  60004.425781  58618.929688  58730.476562   
2021-11-22  58706.847656  59266.359375  55679.839844  56289.289062   
2021-11-23  56304.554688  57875.515625  55632.761719  57569.074219   
2021-11-24  57565.851562  57803.066406  55964.222656  56280.425781   
2021-11-25  57165.417969  59367.968750  57146.683594  57274.679688   
2021-11-26  58960.285156  59183.480469  53569.765625  53569.765625   
2021-11-27  53736.429688  55329.257812  53668.355469  54815.078125   
2021-11-28  54813.023438  57393.843750  53576.734375  57248.457031   
2021-11-29  57474.843750  58749.250000  56856.371094  58749.250000   

               Adj Close       Volume  
Date                                   
2021-10-29  62227.964844  36856881767  
2021-10-30  61888.832031  32157938616  
2021-10-31  61318.957031  32241199927  
2021-11-01  61004.406250  36150572843  
2021-11-02  63226.402344  37746665647  
2021-11-03  62970.046875  36124731509  
2021-11-04  61452.230469  32615846901  
2021-11-05  61125.675781  30605102446  
2021-11-06  61527.480469  29094934221  
2021-11-07  63326.988281  24726754302  
2021-11-08  67566.828125  41125608330  
2021-11-09  66971.828125  42357991721  
2021-11-10  64995.230469  48730828378  
2021-11-11  64949.960938  35880633236  
2021-11-12  64155.941406  36084893887  
2021-11-13  64469.527344  30474228777  
2021-11-14  65466.839844  25122092191  
2021-11-15  63557.871094  30558763548  
2021-11-16  60161.246094  46844335592  
2021-11-17  60368.011719  39178392930  
2021-11-18  56942.136719  41388338699  
2021-11-19  58119.578125  38702407772  
2021-11-20  59697.195312  30624264863  
2021-11-21  58730.476562  26123447605  
2021-11-22  56289.289062  35036121783  
2021-11-23  57569.074219  37485803899  
2021-11-24  56280.425781  36635566789  
2021-11-25  57274.679688  34284016248  
2021-11-26  53569.765625  41810748221  
2021-11-27  54815.078125  30560857714  
2021-11-28  57248.457031  28116886357  
2021-11-29  58749.250000  33326104576
```

Comment: can you add the yf call to get the underlying data? be best to look at that as well. Also, have you checked any other sites to see what the psar looks like for the same timeframe?

Comment: @JonathanLeon I'm not sure what you mean with the yf call. But I added the prices dataframe to the question. Also yes I've looked at tradingview and binance but they still don't match the output from the psar function

Comment: Yeah. That’s it the ohlc data. You had another question where you provided the actual yfinance function to get that data. I’m wondering if your issue is that you are starting in the 29th and not some time before. Sometimes these functions need a period of data to get started before you get valid readings.

Comment: @JonathanLeon Yeah you're right! I changed the period to 10 years and now the data is correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
psar = df.ta.psar(high=df['High'], low=df['Low'], close=df['Close'], af0=0.02, af=0.02, max_af=0.2)
print(psar)

#PSAR r u need

mypsar = pd.DataFrame(psar)["PSARr_0.2_0.2"].iloc[-1] 

            if psar > 0:
                mysartrend = "Bull"
            else:
                mysartrend = "Bear"
print(mysartrend)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).